# How to calculate the 10th and 90th percentile for a mask over a SimpleITK image

Tags: python, histogram, percentile, simpleitk

I want to calculate the 10th and 90th percentile of the pixels within a mask drawn over a simpleITK image. I only can get the mean.

I use the following code:

```
img = sitk.ReadImage(image_path)
label = sitk.ReadImage(label_path)

labelstatsFilter = sitk.LabelIntensityStatisticsImageFilter()
labelstatsFilter.Execute(label, img)
mean = labelstatsFilter.GetMean(1)
```

I couldn't find a method to calculate the percentiles except if I can convert the mask into a numpy array. I couldn't find a way to use the GetArrayfromImage method to work for the mask as it works for the main image.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Use np.extract to extract the mask values for an array then use np.percentile

Example:

```
img = sitk.ReadImage(image_path)
label = sitk.ReadImage(label_path)

img = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(img)
label = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(label)

mask = np.extract(label,img)
10xpercentile= np.percentile(mask,10)
```